# Boost asio send message fail due to broken pipe

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I wrote the following class to send data to server via a ssl connection. Data is packed in protobuf message. It works flawlessly when send and receive one message only (like get and and send heartbeat). But when involve send multiple messages like heartbeat and a another data request message, it failed due to broken pipe.

Example code:

```
SSLHandler conn;//working
while(true){
std::vector<char> msg = buildHearbeatMsg()
conn.writeMessage(msg);
//conn.handleReadMessage(...) get called 
}
SSLHandler conn;//broken pipe
while(true){
std::vector<char> msg = buildHearbeatMsg()
conn.writeMessage(msg);
std::vector<char> msg2 = buildRequestDataMsg()
conn.write(msg);//broken pipe


}
```

The class is

```
#ifndef SSLHANDLER_H
#define SSLHANDLER_H
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>
#include "msg.pb.h"

const int READ_SIZE =0;
const int READ_MSG=1;
class SSLHandler
{
public:




    SSLHandler(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context& context, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
        : socket_(io_service, context) , mEndpointIterator (endpoint_iterator) 
    {
        socket_.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_none);
        socket_.set_verify_callback(boost::bind(&SSLHandler::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));


        mode = READ_SIZE;
    }
    bool verify_certificate(bool preverified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx);
    void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error);
    void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& error);
    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred);
    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred);
    void handle_read_message(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred);
    void connectToServer();
    void writeMessage(std::vector<char> &array);





    void setRequestMsg(std::vector<char> &&array);



private:
    boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator mEndpointIterator;
    char reply_[0x1 << 16]; //=65356 bytes
    int mode;
    uint32_t size;
    std::vector<char> requestMsg;
    std::vector<char> replyMsg;


};

#endif // SSLHANDLER_H



#include "sslhandler.h"

bool SSLHandler::verify_certificate(bool preverified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context &ctx)
{
    char subject_name[256];
    X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
    std::cout << "Verifying:\n" << subject_name << std::endl;

    return preverified;
}

void SSLHandler::handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code &error)
{
    if(!error){
        std::cout << "Connection OK!" << std::endl;
        socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client, boost::bind(&SSLHandler::handle_handshake, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }else{
        std::cout << "Connect failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;

    }
}

void SSLHandler::handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code &error)
{
    if(!error){
        std::cout << "Sending request: " << std::endl;



                boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                                         boost::asio::buffer(requestMsg.data(), requestMsg.size()),
                                         boost::bind(&SSLHandler::handle_write, this,
                                                     boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                     boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }else{
        std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;

    }
}

void SSLHandler::handle_write(const boost::system::error_code &error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error){
        if(mode==READ_SIZE){
            std::cout << "Sending request OK!" << std::endl;
            //      char respond[bytes_transferred] = "";
            boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(reply_,4),
                                    boost::bind(&SSLHandler::handle_read,
                                                this,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
            std::cerr << "respond is " ;
        }
        else if(mode == READ_MSG){
            std::cout << "Sending request OK!" << std::endl;
            //      char respond[bytes_transferred] = "";
            boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(reply_,size),
                                    boost::bind(&SSLHandler::handle_read_message,
                                                this,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
            std::cerr << "respond is " ;
        }


    }else{
        std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;

    }
}

void SSLHandler::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code &error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error){


        std::cout << "Reply: ";
        std::cout.write(reply_, bytes_transferred);
        std::cout << "\n";
        char sizeLittleEndian[4];
    sizeLittleEndian[3] = reply_[0];
        sizeLittleEndian[2] = reply_[1];
        sizeLittleEndian[1] = reply_[2];
        sizeLittleEndian[0] = reply_[3];
        memcpy(&size, sizeLittleEndian,sizeof(uint32_t));
        std::cerr << "size of msg is "  << size;

        boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(reply_,size),
                                boost::bind(&SSLHandler::handle_read_message,
                                            this,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        mode = READ_MSG;




    }else{
        std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;

    }
}

void SSLHandler::handle_read_message(const boost::system::error_code &error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error){



        std::cout << "Reply: ";
        std::cout.write(reply_, bytes_transferred);
        std::cout << "\n";

        replyMsg.assign(reply_,reply_+ size);
        mpConnector->setReadMsg(replyMsg);// upper get 

        mode = READ_SIZE;



    }else{
        std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;

    }
}

void SSLHandler::connectToServer()
{
    boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), mEndpointIterator, boost::bind(&SSLHandler::handle_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void SSLHandler::writeMessage(std::vector<char> &array)
{
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                             boost::asio::buffer(array.data(), array.size()),
                             boost::bind(&SSLHandler::handle_write, this,
                                         boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                         boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
void SSLHandler::setRequestMsg(std::vector<char> &&array)
{
    requestMsg = std::move(array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at reference about `async_write`

> The function call always returns immediately

so if you have code

```
void foo (vector<> data) {
   socket.async_write(); // this function returns immediately
}
```

and you call multiple `foo` functions on the same socket you can get troubles because

> The program must ensure that the stream performs no other write operations (such as async_write, the stream's async_write_some function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until this operation completes.

In your code you call multiple `writeMessage` method of `SSLHandler` on the same connection object, this is incorrect approach.

And the second problem. You must be sure that data which you want to send by socket using `async_write` will still exist until `async_write` ends.
This code is incorrect using `async_write`

```
while(true){
 std::vector<char> msg = buildHearbeatMsg()
 conn.writeMessage(msg);
}
```

you created `msg` as local variable in while scope, then you call `writeMessage` but this function returns immediately and `msg` could be deleted before `async_write` ends working.

Maybe you should use synchronous operations instead of asynchronous to do your task.

Comment: So sorry for the late reply. Your answer was helpful. I implemented a write queue which get dequeue every time async-write is called. That works for me.